# Python Pandas - Multiple rows combining with upcoming date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is an example of my DF (the sku's arent ordered in my df)

```
Sku | Stock | Available_date
AAA | 0     | 20-08-2020
AAA | 50    | 25-08-2020
AAA | 150   | 09-09-2020
BBB | 15    | 20-08-2020
CCC | 0     | 20-08-2020
CCC | 100   | 09-09-2020
DDD | 0     | 20-08-2020
```

***As you can see:***

1. Most of them have multiple rows per SKU
2. It will show the sku on current date (at this moment of writing: 20-08-2020)
3. It will show when the **next** arrival(s) will happen of amount of stocks (for example: for sku AAA it will get 50 on 25-08-2020 and 150 on 09-09-2020)
4. Some sku's (BBB in this case) only have 1 line of just the amount of sku and available date.
5. Some have 0 in stock and Available_date is current date, and thats all..

***Requested output:***

1. When there is on current date 0 stock, take the next date when there is stock
2. When there is stock on current date, replace date with text ('2 days shipping' for example)
3. When there is 0 stock, and only 1 date / row. Set text to 'Unknown'
4. One line for 1 sku with only "Sku" and "Delivery_time"

***Example output in csv for this case:***

```
Sku | Delivery_time
AAA | 25-08-2020
BBB | 2 day shipping
CCC | 09-09-2020
DDD | Unknown
```

How would I need to approach this? I know how to solve an issue when there is only 1 row per sku in dataframe. But how do I solve this issue? I guess we start first by..

```
df.sort_values(by=['SKU', 'Stock'])
```

To sort the pandas dataframe on SKU and Stock.. But then?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is all the stock gone by following day? For example, for Sku `AAA`, is the Stock on Aug 26 equal to 0?

Comment: No. Stock isn't gone the following day.